# POST 404 Not found.. Angular js

Tags: php, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing, angularjs-http

here i'm sending data through $http.post to data/user.php

```
app.factory('loginService',function($http){
    return{
        login:function(data,scope){
            var $promise=$http.post('data/user.php',data); //send data to user.php
            $promise.then(function(msg){
                if(msg.data=='succes') scope.msgtxt='Correct information';
                else                   scope.msgtxt='incorrect information';
            });
        }
    }

});
```

data/user.php code

```
<?php 
    $user=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));  //get user from 
    if($user->mail=='elgaliamine@gmail.com' && $user->pass=='1234') 
        print 'succes';
    else 
        print 'error';
?>
```

and browser continuously showing mePOST `http://localhost:8000/app/data/user.php 404 (Not Found)` 
while m trying `http://localhost:8000/app/data` then it shows there exist `user.php`

Why its giving 404 error?? please do help me...

Comment: Maybe your web server does not have the permissions to access the file in read mode ?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got solution...
actually i am running this whole project under `npm start`

```
http://localhost:8000/app/index.html?#/login
```

so am getting that 404 error

now i've open it under apache

```
http://localhost/login/app/index.html?#/login
```

its working now..

Answer (score 0):

Even I am running the whole project under npm start, I got the same error message.
the thing I was doing wrong was  "  action=" " method="post" 
"

- form class="business_customer" action=" " method="post"  id="contact_form" ng-submit="addDetails()"

I removed  action=" " method="post" from my html and now it works perfectly

- form class="business_customer" id="contact_form" ng-submit="addDetails()"